# Replacing original python

Tags: python

By some need I was forced to correct `os.environ['PATH']` to be able to run `dir\to\fake\python.cmd` script which adds some extra parameters to the original one before execution.

Also I have two python scripts:

**test1.py:**

```
# ...
p = subprocess.call("test2.py")   # shell=True works fine
# ...
```

**test2.py:**

```
# ...
print "Hello from test2.py"
# ...
```

When I run `python test1.py` my "fake" `python.cmd` doing its stuff, refers to the original python in `c:\Python25` and runs `test1.py` with my extra arguments. But, sadly, `test2.py`, script is never called. If I put `shell=True` as `subprocess.call` argument - everythin's fine, `test2.py` is called.

I know, Windows is trying to find python interpreter to use for the call in the real `c:\Python25` working directory when `shell=False` is by default.

The question to you is: how can I achieve the goal without changing my code in `test1.py` and  `test2.py`? Maybe `virtualenv` library may be very useful in this case?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Does `subprocess.call("test2.py")` work if you run `test1.py` with the original python? Is your wrapper called if you run `subprocess.call("test2.py", shell=True)`? What are file associations for `*.py` files on your machine? Do you want to run all python files using `python.cmd`? Why can't you change `test1.py` code to include `shell=True`, what are disadvantages of `shell=True` in this case?

Comment: Why are you using `subprocess.call()` to call a python script?  Just `import test2` in to `test1` and use threading or multiprocess to dispatch a child worker if needed, or just call it directly if it all operates sequentially anyway.  You are already in python code, why go back out to the OS to run other python code?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute.

and

> On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies the default shell. The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch file or console-based executable.

So when you call `subprocess.call("test2.py")`, the system tries to call `test2.py` as an executable, which it is not, so it fails.  However, you don't capture the return value from `subprocess.open` to check for error conditions, so it fails silently.  When you call it with `shell=True`, it calls the system shell with the argument `test2.py`, which in turn looks up the default executable for `.py` files on your system and then executes the file that way.

All that said though, the deeper problem here is that your code is very poorly engineered.  The probability that you have a legitimate reason to dispatch a python script via the OS from another python script is vanishingly small.  Rather than patching another kludgy hack over the top of what you already have, save yourself headaches in the future and refactor the system so that it does things in an easier, more sensible, more naturally integrated way.